# What does 'trout-shouldered' mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context

In an episode of the television show Archer one character refers to another as being "trout-shouldered."

*“This pathetic, trout-shouldered excuse for a boom operator is Chet Manly."*

What might this phrase mean?

Comment: Sounds Wodehousian. It means 'having shoulders like a trout', which one could infer that it means having weak to nonexistent shoulders, therefore slouching and ineffectual. You know, lacking fortitude or the wherewithal to face a new day with vigor and a jutting jaw, a manly stride, to take on the trials and that what's it, the you know what to trample down the slings and et cetera, et cetera, and a little more too... Also, fish-faced = no chin, ibid.

Comment: @Mitch You should apply to the PGW estate to continue the franchise. You've got the language down, and he really only had one plot so that's not a problem ...

Comment: It's always possible the speaker is referring to [baseball player Mike Trout](http://www.thebiglead.com/index.php/2013/02/16/mike-trout-240-pounds-angels-outfielder-fat/), who at least has recognisable shoulders (though as the text points out, he seems to have more bulk in his belly and butt than his shoulders).

Comment: @Mitch in addition to answering my question you also just revealed the inspiration for another character in the show, Woodhouse's, name.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Come on, not even you could mean that. Have you ever *watched* Archer?

Comment: I think @Mitch has the answer in his comment above.

Comment: @Robusto: It was a "tongue-in-cheek" comment, obviously. But in the broader context, until a few weeks ago I'd never watched *any* US tv series for more than a few minutes. Then I downloaded & watched [Breaking Bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad), and mine eyes were opened. Now I just count the days until they air the final episodes *real soon now*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You actually weren't too far afield. They make some pretty obscure references in *Archer* including [a joke](http://www.uproxx.com/tv/2011/01/the-ten-most-obsure-archer-jokes-explained/) about the baseball player Johnny Bench.

Comment: @batpigandme: Having Googled it, I now see that Archer is animation. I actually *do* "pig out" on Family Guy for a few hours every month or two, but I've gradually become aware that there are an awful lot of (probably, not so obscure) references in that one - most of which utterly pass me by. I do find some of the language (and *attitude* to usage variations) in FG fascinating though, and it does seem to have something of a soft spot for BrE in many contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers as a fan of linguistics, you might really enjoy Archer. I am a huge FG fan but I think the jokes in Archer are somehow 'smarter.' They tilt more toward knowledge of history than of pop culture (e.g. "Way to go Oliver Cromwell" when a character 'accidentally' kills the pope). Hard to compare- I really do love them both.

Comment: @batpigandme: Thanks for the info. I'll check it out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My estimation of you as a person of taste and refinement has been reinforced—nay, elevated—now that I see you are a fellow *Breaking Bad* junkie. Side note: The actor who plays Jesse's friend "Badger" was asked what was his favorite thing about being on the show. He replied that it was because fans of the show actually get mad at their friends if they *don't* watch it. ^)^

Comment: @Robusto: I (cough, cough) swiped all BB episodes to date via P2P a while back, but only recently got around to watching them. I realised I was addicted fairly quickly, but until I actually finished S05E08 and started looking for my next fix, I had no idea I was going to have to go cold turkey until [August 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad_(season_5)). And even then I suppose I'll only get one hit a week (IMHO, it's a deliberately-created addiction, on a par with Big Tobacco! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers check out Never Gonna Cook Together on YouTube by TeddyFilms - warms the BB lovers soul!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Trout-shouldered' presumably means

> having shoulders like a trout.

This probably means that the writer is implying that person so labeled doesn't have very strong shoulders and so is somewhat weak. This is implying not physical weakness but metaphorical weakness of character.

It is not a set-phrase or idiom meaning something outside of its implications.